# "Sites to see" or "Sights to see"?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

A google search turns up results for either.  The two are seemingly interchangeable. Which is it?  Does one see sights or see sites?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Sights* is the word used for interesting places to see, often visited by tourists. *Sites* can be any place where something happened, or that is used for something (e.g. an archeological site, the site of the battle, a camping site).

The phrase normally used is *sights to see*.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, there is a wide range of meanings which cover both words, so they can be used as you pointed out.

[sites](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/site) :

> - an area of land where something is being built or could be built
> - a place where something happened, especially something interesting orimportant, or where there is an important building
> - a place used for a particular purpose
> - website

E.g; *We have seen the site, it's beautiful.*

[sights](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sight) :

> - the ability to see using your eyes
> - interesting places that people go to see
> - a person or thing that you see that has a particular feature
> - a person or place that is very unusual, messy, or unpleasant to look at
> - the part of a gun or other piece of equipment that you look through in order to aim it

E.g; *The Hermitage Museum is one of the most important sights to see for any visitor to St. Petersburg.*

*See the sights* is also an [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+the+sights).

1) We plan to visit Paris and see the sights.
2) Everyone left the hotel early in the morning to see the sights.

Comment: Please quote your sources and use the `` instead of {} and paste the whole part of the sentence or edit it.

Comment: @mplungjan; well i provided the links for the sake of reference only, have added a few examples to further clarify what i answered.